# Facebook events to RSS feed?

Tags: php, xml, facebook, rss

It looks like there used to be an export events button (to RSS), but Facebook 
has removed it. I've looked at fbCal, but it only exports the event name and the link to the event, but none of the event details.

How can I get multiple event details out of Facebook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the [events.get](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Events.get) API call, you can get all the (public) events for a particular user and render your RSS feed from that data.